# Create an opaque Text box on top of an image?

Tags: css, html

I am a newbie to both html and css and for the life of me I cannot get this right. Can someone please assist me in coding this?

[image: image of the desired effect]

This is what I have done so far, but now I'm stuck and my image is not showing up at all..

```html
<div class="image"></div>

<div id="box1"> 
    <h2>Welcome to the home of</h2>
    <h1>Oliver & Sons</h1>
    <p title="Oliver & Sons - Exquisite Carpentry">
        In my workshop patience, skill and immaculate precision are combined to produce items that is unique, of exquisite taste and quality and could very well be a heirloom in your family. Explore my gallery and contact me when you are ready to experience craftsmanship at it’s best.
    </p>
</div>
```

```css
#box1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100%px;
    border: 2px solid navy;
    margin: 0px;
    background-colour: white;
}

div.image {
    background: url(Images/background.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Start with the basics - it looks like you need an element with a background image. Can you give that a shot?

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please consider re-opening this question. I have edited my answer to show the code I have done so far. I really need help with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a several wrong things here:

1. When you set any CSS property like padding you should only use one kind of messure: `px`, `%`, `em`, `rem`... But not two, as you do in `#box1`. This is an error.
2. This is matter of style. When you set a property to 0 is better not set `px`, nor any kind of messurement units.

Now, your goal.

You want to get your `#box1` inside of your `.image` so you should put one tag inside of another, as you could see on my code. Doing that you will be very close to your solution.

Next thing is centering you `#box1`. There are a lot of ways to do that, I put here my favourite, but, as always, the best way depends on the situation.

```css
#box1 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid navy;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
  background: navy;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 5px
}

div.image {
  padding: 20px;
  background: url(http://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/094/491/original/polygonal-texture-background-vector.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

  <div id="box1">
    <h2>Welcome to the home of</h2>
    <h1>Oliver & Sons</h1>
    <p title="Oliver & Sons - Exquisite Carpentry">
      In my workshop patience, skill and immaculate precision are combined to produce items that is unique, of exquisite taste and quality and could very well be a heirloom in your family. Explore my gallery and contact me when you are ready to experience craftsmanship
      at it’s best.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much. Just a question, as you mentioned earlier I should not be using % and px in the same css property. If I only use % how do I work out the percentages?

Comment: When you set a meassure using percentages you are taking the meassures related to the parent. So if the parent has a width of 1000px and the child's width is 50%, the browser will set the child's width to 500px

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the outer container will be a background image, then you will have another container to hold the text which will could use the the background-color: RGBA property.

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}

.container {
     height: 100%;
     background: url(link/to/image) center center;
     background-size: cover; 
     // Use prefixes
}

.inner-container {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: #000;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
```

Please make sure you explain as much as possible in your example code, SO isn't here to code for you :)

Here is a pretty useful link explaining RBGA

https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: This answer gives you a jump start to your requirement.

Comment: Please consider re-opening this question. I have edited my answer to show the code I have done so far. I really need help with this..